# SELECT Specefic Date in Tsql Query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables that are joined together with this query.
One of them brings me people names , another one brings me their points and the last one brings me date time.

I select the total people score.

Also, there is a column in the 3th tables that brings me the scores' transaction `Date Time`. My problem is that I want to write a TSQL query with this condition:

Select the transaction date where the people score is 12,000 or more.

In my idea I should use while loop but I do not know the syntax?

[image]

Comment: You should while??? What does that mean? Are you trying to do a running total and want to know the date the total score exceeds a certain value? What version of sql-server?

Comment: sorry , i edited my question

Comment: What version of sql-server? Here are several ways to get running totals. A while loop is not a good choice. http://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/grouped-running-totals

Comment: @salar, can you show the column names of all three tables instead of image,copy the schema , with sample data.

Comment: seems like all you would need to add is a Condition : `HAVING SUM(Points) >= 12000` and maybe make the join a `right outer join`.  Also this query only uses 2 tables

Comment: sorry guys , i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your post this should be close to what you need.  You need to add that 3rd table and alter this statement accordingly.

```
SELECT cp.FirstName
    ,  cp.LastName
    ,  SUM(Points) as Score

    FROM [fidilio].[dbo].[ClubProfile] cp 
        RIGHT JOIN ( 
            CardTransaction ct 
                INNER JOIN CardTransactionLog ctl
                    ON cp.CardTransactionLogId = ctl.CardTransactionLogId
            )
            ON cp.ClubProfileId = ct.ClubProfileId
    GROUP BY 
            cp.FirstName
         ,  cp.LastName

    HAVING  SUM(Points) >=12000 
        AND ctl.TransactionTimeStamp = @SomeDateTimeVariable
```

The variable @SomeDateTimeVariable has to come from someplace what is your exact time-frame criteria

Comment: Thank you @fnostro, my problem is that how i can select date time that HAVING SUM(Points) >=12000

Comment: is the datetime field associated with each CardTransaction or with the individual?

Comment: it s associated with card transaction

Comment: ooooo a nested join - I have to remember the syntax for that...brb

Comment: please my friend , tomorrow i should finish this query

Comment: I think this is correct - you may have to play with it a bit.  And may need to adjust the Date criteria.  Hope this helps

Comment: till here i know that , after that it s important for me

Comment: can you explain me about my datetime param?

Comment: I made a guess just to include it in the syntax, I didn't have the field name but I see it now - but based on your table relations there is a 1-to-many  from ClubProfile to Transactions and a 1-to-1 from Transactions to TransactionLog.  I assumed you need all the Transactions equal to a certain date, that's a guess on my part.  What is the exact criteria.

Comment: if you see my image , my date time column is name timestamp . as i said this points have date time . and people have points

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it-

```
SELECT cp.FirstName
,  cp.LastName
,  SUM(Points) as Score
FROM ClubProfile cp 
    RIGHT JOIN CardTransaction ct 
        ON cp.ClubProfileId = ct.ClubProfileId
    INNER JOIN Your3rdTable as t3
        ON cp.ClubProfileId = t3.ClubProfileId
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, ct.[Date Column], 101) = @your_date_param
GROUP BY 
        cp.FirstName
     ,  cp.LastName
HAVING SUM(Points) >=12000
```

Comment: Thank you @briskovich , can you explain me what is   your_date_param

Comment: Yeah what every date you want to filter with. So like CONVERT(VARCHAR, ct.[Date Column], 101) = '01/15/2015' or whatever date you choose.

Comment: thank you , but my problem is that  i want to select date time .the date time when sum( point) more than 12000

Comment: Your having clause is only going to return rows that meet that condition.

Comment: whats that mean ? would you  mind explain ? these points have date time . when their sum be more than 12000 , this is that i want

Comment: The HAVING clause is your filter for sums greater than 1200.

Comment: ok @briskovich now with this condition how can select date time , by the way ,thank you for you attention man

Comment: The date column isn't in your select. You can just select the date column there and it will filter with your having clause.